# Configuring JWT for NGINX PLUS controller in kubernetes

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, jwt

I have got NGINX in place as of now which acts as a load balancer. When i was creating the Ingress for my Nginx Controller, the details that i had provided in Ingress file were updated in the containers nginx.conf file.

For example:

```
upstream default-hello-8123   
{ # Load balance algorithm; empty for round robin, which is the default
 least_conn;  
  keepalive 32;  
  server x.x.x.x:xx max_fails=0 fail_timeout=0;  
}
```

I had above details in the Ingress file. Once I deployed my Ingress service / Controller / Ingress. nginx.conf was updated automatically.

I was trying to configure JWT for authentication now. But i could not figure if there is a way to that configuration as well such as below to be updated automatically in the nginx.conf instead of writing it manually.

```
server {  
    listen 80;   
    location /products/ {  
        auth_jwt "Products API";
        auth_jwt_key_file conf/api_secret.jwk;  
        proxy_pass http://api_server;  
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I assume you have configured your ingress via annotations. If not, read here:

https://github.com/nginxinc/kubernetes-ingress/tree/master/examples/jwt

**IMPORTANT**: this whole answer is only applicable by using the [NGINX Ingress Controller](https://github.com/nginxinc/kubernetes-ingress) as opposed to the Kubernetes Ingress Controller. Read about the key differences [here](https://github.com/nginxinc/kubernetes-ingress/blob/master/docs/nginx-ingress-controllers.md).

Basically, there are two minimum requirements:

Start by creating a [Secret](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/) first. There are multiple ways to do it but here is an example using `kubectl`:

```
kubectl create secret generic my-jwk --from-file=/path/to/your/key
```

where the key file looks like

```
# Example from: https://www.nginx.com/blog/authenticating-api-clients-jwt-nginx-plus/#page-7
{"keys":
    [{
        "k":"YOUR_BASE64_ENCODED_SECRET",
        "kty":"oct",
        "kid":"0001"
    }]
}
```

In this case **it is important your jwk file is named `jwk`** because the NGINX Ingress Controller expects the keys to exist in the `jwk` field and generating Secrets using the `--from-file` attribute assigns the file contents to a key matching the filename.

This fulfills the first hard requirement and the other requirement is to ensure that your authenticating app uses the expected JWT delivery. By default, a JWT is expected in the `Authorization` header as a Bearer Token.

Next, You should reference to that Secret, named `my-jwk` to the Ingress Controller via annotation:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: my-ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.com/jwt-key: "my-jwk" 
spec:
# .. fill in the rest of your spec here.
```

That is the only annotation required.

There are other annotations you can use. However, they are optional. Taken from the first README link on this answer:

> - Optional: nginx.com/jwt-realm: "realm" -- specifies a realm.
> - Optional: nginx.com/jwt-token: "token" -- specifies a variable that
>   contains JSON Web Token. By default, a JWT is expected in the
>   Authorization header as a Bearer Token.
> - Optional:   nginx.com/jwt-login-url: "url" -- specifies a URL to which a client is redirected in case of an invalid or missing JWT.

Comment: The public key is usually exposed through a public REST API (Keycloak does it) - is there support for that? (annotation to retrieve the key )

Comment: Perfect answer but we got error with the key  due to the fact that the secret must have the type `nginx.org/jwk` : 
`kubectl create secret generic my-jwk --from-file=/path/to/your/key --type "nginx.org/jwk"`